# How to check if anonymous array is empty in perl

Tags: perl

So I have the following script that I'm messing around with to understand perl's anonymous array. I'm trying to check if it's empty or not, however the if check passes instead of the else check which I want to happen. Thanks in advance!

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;


my $result = [];

print STDOUT Dumper $result;

if ($result)
{
    print STDOUT "It has stuff in it\n";
}
else
{
    print STDOUT "It is empty!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dereference:

```
if (@$result) {
    print "Has stuff\n";
} else {
    print "Empty\n";
}
```